# How can I call one of multiple arrays by its name through a variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I am trying to call values from an array and have the name of the array be chosen by a string from another variable. So say I have two arrays. I then want to choose which array the data is pulled from through a string in a variable.

```
const notes = ['A','A#','B','C','C#','D','D#','E','F','F#','G','G#','A','A#','B','C','C#','D','D#','E','F','F#','G','G#','A'];
const minor = [0,2,3,5,7,8,10,12];
const major = [0,2,4,5,7,9,11,12];

let keyRoot = 5;
let keyScale = 'minor';

let output = "";
if (keyScale === 'minor'){
   for(let i=0; i<8; i++){
        let songKey = keyRoot -1 + minor[i]

        output += notes[songKey]
        output += ' '
    }    
}


console.log(output);
```

What I want to do is pretty much remove the if statement and call the arrays minor and major with the variable keyScale, as the number of Scales will likely exceed only minor and major and I feel like there has to be a more efficient way than to check every possibilty with if statements. keyScale and keyRoot will be set on the interface through buttons. I have only set them in this example to get an output.
So I want it to look somewhat like this

```
const notes = ['A','A#','B','C','C#','D','D#','E','F','F#','G','G#','A','A#','B','C','C#','D','D#','E','F','F#','G','G#','A'];
const minor = [0,2,3,5,7,8,10,12];
const major = [0,2,4,5,7,9,11,12];

let keyRoot = 5;
let keyScale = 'minor';

let output = "";
   for(let i=0; i<8; i++){
        let songKey = keyRoot -1 + keyScale[i]

        output += notes[songKey]
        output += ' '
    }    



console.log(output);
```

Comment: Put your arrays in an object as property values and then it's easy, you just reference the object properties with `[keyScale]` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create object:

```
const arrays = {
  minor,
  major
}
```

Get array:

```
arrays[keyScale]
```

```js
const notes = ['A', 'A#', 'B', 'C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#', 'A', 'A#', 'B', 'C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#', 'A'];
const minor = [0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12];
const major = [0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12];

const arrays = {
  minor,
  major
}

let keyRoot = 5;
let keyScale = 'minor';

let output = "";
for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  let songKey = keyRoot - 1 + arrays[keyScale][i]

  output += notes[songKey]
  output += ' '
}



console.log(output);
```